# Does a gas move from a region of high to low pressure according to it's own partial pressure rather than the total gas pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, gas

I have a plastic bottle that is impermeable to ${\rm CO}_2$ but slightly permeable to $\rm O_2$.

If I fill up the bottle with pure $\rm CO_2$ at $3$ atmospheres and expose it to $\rm O_2$ at $1$ atmosphere, will $\rm O_2$ enter the bottle? My understanding is that gases move from high to low partial pressure independent of other gases. Is this true?

Comment: Hi! What kind of bottle is it?

Comment: How do you maintain the pressure difference?  Perhaps a Gedanken filter which passes O2 but does not allow CO2  to pass thru?

Comment: Similar https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/565575/why-would-tennis-balls-filled-with-sulfur-hexafluoride-explode

Answer (score 4):

In an ideal case in which particles don't interact, or in the limit of dilute gas, yes. Because the bottle contains no $O_2$ then the gas is more likely to enter the bottle than to leave it (because... there is no $O_2$ inside) so you have a net diffusive flow inside the bottle. That is, until the bottle reaches a (partial) pressure so high that the outgoing flow of $O_2$ (the molecules that was outside, randomly entered the bottle, and now randomly leaves) balances the incoming one.

In a more complex but more general case, where particles interact (either same-gas particles interact with each other or $O_2$ interacting with $CO_2$ (not always the case for these two gases, but for two other gases it could happen) and/or gas particles occupy a volume, then higher order effects might play a role (in the limit, if the bottle has no free space because the $CO_2$ is filling it completely then of course $O_2$ won't enter. But if you put in the numbers you see that for that to happen you need huge amounts of gas).
Imagine you have 100 moles of $CO_2$ in that bottle. Then, if you approximate a $CO_2$ molecule as a sphere of radius $0.15 nm$ then you get that 100 moles *completely* fill out a 1L bottle, there is literally no "empty" space left. In that case, $O_2$ would not enter - but this is far from ideal/dilute conditions (and would also need a bottle with very strong pressure resistance)!

As a first approximation, you can use a [Van der Waals gas model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation#Gas_mixture), where particles have an interaction and a volume, and then when the gas is not in dilute conditions anymore, the partial pressure concept fails.

But in the ideal case / dilute case, partial pressure law holds and $O_2$ would diffuse inside the bottle.

Comment: Given that a gas always diffuse in all available space, how would you specificaly define the situation where CO2 fills completly the bottle to the point that O2 wont enter ? CO2 always fills completly the bottle even at low pressure.

Comment: I meant litterally fill the bottle, as in "there is no room left at all". CO2 molecules have a volume, imagine them as a sphere of 0.15 nm in radius. If you have ~100 moles of CO2 they fill out completely a 1L bottle. That is an unlikely situation but of course then O2 would not be able to enter as there is literally no space left. A more physical model would be using a Van der Waals kind of model, where molecules have an attraction and a volume, and then partial pressure law becomes invalid: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation#Gas_mixture - still, I am editing for clarity

Comment: Now imagine the bottle is not permeable to both O2 and CO2 gases. You make a little hole in it. CO2 will exit by the hole. Do you think, O2 molecules will find their way across the CO2 flow to enter the bottle ?

Comment: That depends on the level of approximation you look at the problem. If the molecules interact, they will interfere and so $O_2$ might be blocked by the CO2 flow. If they are ideal gases / very dilute, $O_2$ will flow in. So the answer stays the same: if the gas is ideal, O2 will flow in as if CO2 is not in there. Otherwise, it will depend on the model.

Answer (score 2):

This is the gaseaous analogue of [*osmotic pressure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmotic_pressure) with the plastic bottle playing the role of the semipermeable membrane. In equilibrium the ${\rm O}_2$ pressure will be the same within as without, and inside    there will be ${\rm CO}_2$ pressure as well. The total pressure inside will therefore be be higher and may even burst the bottle.

Comment: Where would the energy required to burst the bottle come from ?

Comment: The energy comes from reduction in the free energy of  of the bottle without oxygen. The entropy increases as the oxygen penertates so $\Delta F =-T\Delta S$ is negtive. It's the same as bacteria being burst by osmotic pressure.