# Osmotic pressure "equilibrium"?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, equilibrium, osmosis

Consider a box with two compartments separated by a semipermeable membrane. The first compartment is initially at pressure $P_0$ and contains the solvent ; the second compartment is initially at pressure $P_1$ and contains the solvent and a solute.

In deriving the van't Hoff my textbook says that we consider the system at equilibrium , yet it says that the two pressures are different at equilibrium. Isn't equality of pressures of subsystems a condition for equilibrium?

Comment: No, equality of _partial_ pressures applies for a semipermeable membrane. Only one component can sample both volumes and come to equilibrium between them, the other (that can't pass the membrane) cannot sample the other side.

Comment: @Jon Custer I don't quite understand , if we wait some time the concentrations hence the pressures should equalize , no? Hence the system is not at equilibrium to begin with

Comment: Is the membrane movable? Regardless of the presence of osmosis, a fixed barrier can certainly sustain a pressure difference. In addition, matter moves to the region of lowest [chemical potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/363816/146039), not necessarily to the region of lowest pressure.

Comment: See, for example, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/565575/

Comment: @Chemomechanics the membrane is fixed,

Comment: @Chemomechanics so you are saying that the initial pressures/concentration remain fixed for all time ? Shouldn't the system tend to evolve to a state where the concentrations/pressures are equal ?

Comment: Matter moves to equalize [chemical potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_potential) gradients, not necessarily concentration or pressure gradients.

Comment: @Chemomechanics ok yes I agree, but the definition of equilibrium requires all of the parts of a system to have equal pressure ? Am I missing something here ?

Comment: There can be any number of "transport complexes" in which certain interactions are coupled so that in equilibrium some individual potentials do not have to be equalized, but their *joint* effort is. For example, a fluid with surface tension, where the internal potential is not the same as external potential if surface tension is included. Other example is a vertical column gas in gravitational field, where the gravito-chemical potential must be equalized but the chemical potential itself may have a nontrivial gradient in equilibrium.

Comment: @lohey If the boundary is fixed, the system can't progress any closer to mechanical equilibrium between two chambers at different pressures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In thermodynamics we can have partial equilibrium depending on the presence or absence of constraints. Suppose we divide a box into two parts: the equilibrium conditions between the two parts depend on the the properties of the wall:

- If the wall is impermeable, fixed, and conducting, we only have *thermal* equilibrium. The pressure and chemical potentials in each part are not allowed to equilibrate.
- If the wall is impermeable, movable and insulating, then we only have *mechanical* equilibrium. i.e., pressure is equalized but temperature and chemical potential are not.
- In the osmotic experiment the wall is fixed, conducting and semipermeable. This leads to *thermal* and *chemical* equilibrium between two parts that are at different pressures.